# How to backup SQL Server 2014 database with SC Data Protection Manager using SQL script

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2014, dpm

I'm trying to set up the database maintenance solution for SQL Server 2014 using [this](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html) SQL script and System Center Data Protection Manager 2012 r2 as a BackupSoftware (like SQLSAFE, SQLBACKUP and SQLSAFE)

1. Does anyone now which DPM backup procedures are needed to be called directly from SQL Server Management Studio to backup a database?
2. Is there any other way how to backup sql server 2014 databases using DPM? Cmdlets?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What's wrong with DPM's built-in SQL instance backup?

Comment: I love [Ola Hallengren](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html)'s scripts. Someone in my organization just showed me DPM's SQL Server protection functionality today. It seemed to us like a [Black Box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_box). For many of us DBAs, it's hard to trust something when you don't know exactly what it's doing. I was like the OP: if only DPM was showing me some scripts or jobs in SSMS so I could know what it was doing...